# Merge Replication Finding Session Id

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I am using merge replication with SQL 2012.

I am writing a custom business logic handler, and would like to know if there is a way to get a session id?

For instance if the custom business logic handler catches an insert into a specific table, and then the custom business logic handler catches an insert into another table, how can you tell if they are part of the same session?

Also by session_id I am referring to something like the session_id which is in the MSMerge_sessions table.